# Copy 1 column from 100 different Excel paths to 1 Excel file using XL wings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xlwings

```
wb=xw.Book()
for i in ripPaths:   
     wbtemp=xw.Book(i)
     my_values=wbtemp.sheets['sheet1'].range('B5:B4722').options(ndim=2).value
     wb.sheets['sheet1'].range("A1:A4722").value=my_values
```

I am trying to open 100 excel files I have on my disk successively using the for loop, and then copy the same column from each and paste it into another excel file. The problem is that I keep overwriting ColumnA. I need the A1:A4722 in line 5 to increment to B, C, D, through excel column names.
I'm stuck in the mud!

The goal is to take my 100 excel docs with 1 column each to make a new excel file with 100 excel columns. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wb=xw.Book()
for i in range(3):   
     wbtemp=xw.Book(ripPaths[i])
   my_values=wbtemp.sheets['sheet1'].range('B5:B4722').options(ndim=2).value
     wb.sheets.active.range((1,i+1)).value=my_values
```

Aditya's answer with f strings is sick, but this is smoother. Thanks for the tip, Felix.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's my take on it. Letters for this type of thing would be complex since Excel can loop from A-Z and then AA-AZ, etc, however: here's a method:

```py
wb=xw.Book()
for i in range(len(ripPaths)):   
     wbtemp=xw.Book(ripPaths[i])
     my_values=wbtemp.sheets['sheet1'].range('B5:B4722').options(ndim=2).value
     if i < 26:
        wb.sheets['sheet1'].range(f"{chr(65+i)}1:{chr(65+i)}4722").value=my_values
     elif i < 52:
        wb.sheets['sheet1'].range(f"A{chr(39+i)}1:A{chr(39+i)}4722").value=my_values
     elif i < 78:
        wb.sheets['sheet1'].range(f"B{chr(13+i)}1:B{chr(13+i)}4722").value=my_values
     elif i < 104:
        wb.sheets['sheet1'].range(f"C{chr(-13+i)}1:C{chr(-13+i)}4722").value=my_values
```

This uses f-strings, you can use another form of string formatting if you so choose.

Comment: This is very helpful. Great idea for a problem I should not have got myself into. Thanks Aditya!

Comment: Glad I could help! Alternatively you can use a modulus type thing off of 26 to simplify this, but if this is a one time run script, I don't see the need.

Comment: Have a look at the syntax overview in the docs: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/syntax_overview.html#active-objects You can use indices, too which are much easier to loop than A1 references.

Answer (score 0):

```
dst_wb = xw.Book()
sh = wb.sheets['sheet1']
for i, path in enumerate(ripPaths):   
     scr_wb = xw.Book(path)
     src_sh = scr_wb.sheets['sheet1']
     values = src_sh['B5:B4722'].options(ndim=2).value
     sh[0,i].value= values
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for taking the time to add an answer. Please check out the guide to [answer]. This post would benefit from an explanation indicating what your code is doing and why it adds useful new information to the existing set of answers. Since this question is now several years old, the "usefulness" bar is a little higher and it would be good to hear from you (by editing your answer) why you think this answer is needed and helpful. Thanks!